Is it Normal to End up with "Reciprocal Rules" in Market Basket Analysis
I ran my first market basket analysis.  However, it looks like each rules has a reciprocal.  is this normal? If the rules are duplicates why do they differ by conviction and which rule of each dyad is "correct"?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
The online examples I can find don't show this relationship:
[https://github.com/hyunjoonbok/Python-Projects/blob/master/GeneralML/Cohort_Basket_Analysis/Market%20Basket%20Analysis%20101%20with%20Real%20Example%20-%20Association%20rules%2C%20Lift%2C%20Confidence%2C%20Support.ipynb][2]
[https://goldinlocks.github.io/Market-Basket-Analysis-in-Python/][3]
My code is (without internal checks):
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.crosstab(df['Member_number'], df['itemDescription'])
df2.head()

def encode(item_freq):
    res = 0
    if item_freq > 0:
        res = 1
    return res
    
basket_input = df2.map(encode)

basket_input = basket_input.astype(bool)

pip install xlrd

from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import fpgrowth ## more efficient than apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules

frequent_itemsets = fpgrowth(basket_input, min_support=0.001, use_colnames=True)

rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="lift")

rules.sort_values(["support", "confidence", "lift"],axis = 0, ascending = False).head(30)




  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/iuZdEhj8.png
  [2]: https://github.com/hyunjoonbok/Python-Projects/blob/master/GeneralML/Cohort_Basket_Analysis/Market%20Basket%20Analysis%20101%20with%20Real%20Example%20-%20Association%20rules%2C%20Lift%2C%20Confidence%2C%20Support.ipynb
  [3]: https://goldinlocks.github.io/Market-Basket-Analysis-in-Python/

